# Saving string array in mySql using JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project that has students and games.
**Game** can have many **questions** and each **question** has **choices** that are just **strings** so is there a way to not make a table for choices and would that be the right thing or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity and coding convention having option string in table will be great ease for you when render question and and their choices dynamically and storing the answers of questions.

There will `less data redundancy` and hence much `reduced database size`.

Comment: I'm working with SOA so how would i receive the questions, and thanks for replying.

Comment: That's another question! I would suggest posting another question with problem details and code! Don't forget to be precise and your tryouts!